# Why are formulas in Physics represented in form of differentiation?

Tags: differentiation, calculus

Mostly formulas are represented in differential form as we learn more about the concepts of physics ,
for ex.
$I = \frac {q}{t}$ is also written as $\frac {dq}{dt}$

A explanation would help .

Comment: Determining how systems evolve over time is one aspect we are trying to study in Physics. Since time is a continuous quantity, a differentiation with respect to time usually is what we use to determine said evolution.

Comment: "is also written as" ...this is the problem: they are two different concepts, and the first one is just a "baby" way to introduce the second one. However, mathematically, they are not the same thing (exactly as the average velocity is not the istantaneous velocity, they coincide only if the velocity is constant).

Comment: This is correct only if I is not depending on t . 
$\begin{aligned}\int dq=\int Idt\\
q=It\end{aligned}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In physics, observables are usually modeled as numerical quantities, and laws are relations between these quantites.

A mathematical relation between numerical quantities, typically showing how one quantity reacts when another varies, is precisely a differential equation or a partial derivative equation (at least when those quantities are continuous).

In some cases, especially in modern physics, observables are modeled as quantities that aren't numbers, but they are still quantities for which differential relationships can be established.

Take the example of velocity. If you run at constant speed and measure the distance covered and the time it took, $v=x/t$ will be an accurate measurement of your speed during the run. If, however, your speed changed during the run, $v=x/t$ will just be your average speed and it will no longer accurately measure your speed at a given instant.

So you'll find yourself slicing up your run into phases: in phase 1 your velocity was $v_1$, in phase 2 it was $v_2$, and so on.

If your speed changes constantly, the phases will have *vanishingly small* durations, which we usually write $dt$. Then the variation of position during a phase will be small too and will be written as $dx$.

So the same formula $v=x/t$ becomes $v=dx/dt$.

In other words, when a quantity can continuously vary due to the continuous variations of others, the relationship between them becomes differential.

Answer (score 0):

> Mostly formulas are represented in differential form.

As you mentioned yes, most of the formulas is written in differential form. It comes from one of the most important branch of *Mathematics* called *calculus*. As example we take, $dx\over dy$.

It means that the term $x$ changes with respect to $y$.

As you mentioned flow of current, $I = \frac {dq}{dt}$ means flow of current equals to flow of charge ($q$) with respect to time ($t$) .

Hope this helps.